Optimizing Path Through Large Directed Acyclic Graph Tree
This is a rephrasing/different approach to Fitting curve with restricted relative orientations.
I have a directed acyclic graph that flows from Level 0 to Level 3500. Edges only occur between levels, not within levels (e.g. a Level 1 node connects to several Level 2 nodes, Level 2 nodes never connect to Level 2 nodes).
Each Level N node is connected to between 1 and 9 Level N+1 nodes. This causes the tree to grow very rapidly - Level 3500 has something like 8^3500 Nodes.
The goal is to find a path from Level 0 to Level 3500 that has the lowest maximum node value. I've highlighted a couple paths in the image. I only care about the maximum node value, not the total path value. I can also get a starting path that provides a good but non-optimal path.
While I would like to be able to find the optimal route, I would accept being able to find a route that is within say 20% or 50% of optimal.
My current approach:

Calculated a good but non-optimal path to give a starting maximum node value (not shown)
Proceed depth first, calculating node values as they are encountered. Using the right side of the graph I would calculate L0=0.1, L1=0.1, L2=0.2. The cost of this path is then 0.2
Move up the graph until I reach a cost of <0.2 - in this case it occurs at L1=0.1.
Investigate the other nodes connected to this node to see if they are lower value. L2=0.3, so no.
Therefore move up the tree to L0 and investigate down again.
L2=0.2, therefore it is not an improvement and can be ignored.
L2=0.1, good, continue to investigate
L3=0.1, good, therefore best path is now 0.1 and can't be improved upon because L0=0.1.

Optimization occurs by moving up the tree (up levels) and choosing a different path down.
Due to the number of nodes, even short trees (10 levels) take too long to optimize.
If you are at Level 1, determining the values of the Level 2 nodes connected to you takes about 1/100 of a second.
Is there another approach to this problem?
For example, I can get a pretty good, non-optimal solution for the tree in about 10 minutes using a method like nearest neighbor.


"Level 3500 has something like 8^3500 Nodes": impossible to have such a large tree. It's not going to happen in this universe. You won't even be able to build all the nodes in level 20.

Many branches of the tree can be eliminated by levels above them. I can get an non-optimal result - say Max Node of 0.1 - which means I can eliminate all branches where a node value is > 0.1, so not all nodes/branches need to be evaluated. As shown in the figure, the optimal path was found after evaluating 7 of the 14 nodes. The middle branch was never considered after Level 1.

I am not talking about considering branches. I'm talking about even having the tree in memory (or disk, or on a skyscraper full of supercomputers): "something like 8^3500" does not exist.

But why does the whole tree have to be in memory? Don't we only need awareness of nodes that have a meaningful impact to the problem? For example, I can get a pretty good, non-optimal solution in about 10 minutes using a method like nearest neighbor.

For example, I can get a pretty good, non-optimal solution for the tree in about 10 minutes using a method like nearest neighbor.

If you don't have the graph in memory where do you get its node values and node's children from?

Level 2 nodes can be calculated from knowledge of a Level 1 node. This graph is attempting to optimize a polyline that is trying to follow a design alignment. The polyline has certain allowable angles between segments. This is explained in greater detail in the linked question. I was trying to abstract the question from the physical system to gain different perspectives.
